# MongoDB: How to query over a json string?

Tags: mongodb

There's a MongoDB collection that was populated with documents like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7f83b591fae49715443590"),
    "content" : "{\n\t\"email\":\"username@domain.com\",\n\t\"country_code\": \"US\"\n}"
}
```

As you can see `"content"`has a JSON string

I was able to parse the string using `JSON.parse()` like:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({}).map(function(doc){ return {'_id':doc._id, 'content': JSON.parse(doc.content)}});
```

Giving me an array of objects with `_id` and `content` as an object.

Is there a way to execute queries (filtering, aggregate functions) over `content` preferably without getting an array from `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like you said In terms of the database `content` is a string. So you need to save the entire collection where `content` will be a object so you will be able to filtering, aggregate etc...